# 16.04 problem uploading with Chrome, Ixdg-open open? doesn´t work

Tags: google-chrome, upload, xdg-open, default-browser

My Ubuntu 16.04 system can't upload from Chrome. It says:

> Please click Open xdg-open if you see the system dialog.
>   If nothing prompts from browser, click here to launch the meeting, or download & run Zoom.

And than it said

> Your browser doesn't support using computer's Audio device, please upgrade your browser to the latest version.
>   google-chrome-stabel, install.

But that doesn't work. How can I troubleshoot this to solve it?

Comment: 1) Does this occur when you try to upload from Mozilla Firefox? 2) Does this happen when you install the Chromium browser by _sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y chromium-browser_ and try to upload from it? 3) If the answers to 1 and 2 are yes, what is the website you are trying to upload to? Please click [edit] and let us know the results of 1-3. Please do not use Add Comment, which is our channel to you.